# Given a relation between two variables, find another.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $\frac{2x+y}{x-2y}=\frac34$, find the value of $\frac{x}{2y}$.

How do I do this?  I was thinking of making the first fractions $\frac{x}{2y}$ but I don't think it will work.

Please help.  (This is just an example, I've got a page of these to do.)

Comment: While you are learning enough Latex to typeset questions so they are easy to read, please use parentheses. Your expression should have looked like (2x+y)/(x-2y) = 3/4.

Answer (score 4):

We have $\dfrac{2x+y}{x-2y}=\dfrac{3}{4}$, so $4(2x+y)=3(x-2y)$, so $8x+4y=3x-6y$, so $5x=-10y$, so $\dfrac{x}{y}=-2$, so $\dfrac{x}{2y}=-1$.